# How to add foreign key to table in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

What I am doing incorrect? Trying to create these tables in sqlfiddle
 does not work gives

```
Cannot add foreign key constraint

create table product (
  pid int NOT NULL,
  name varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (pid)
);

create table trans (
  tid int NOT NULL ,
  productId int NOT NULL,
  userId int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (tid),
  FOREIGN KEY (productId) REFERENCES product(pid),
  FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES user1(uid)
);

create table user1 (
  uid int NOT NULL ,
  location varchar(22),
  PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);
```

Comment: You need to create the `product` and `user1` tables before they can be referenced by foreign keys. Move the `trans` table to the last position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BillKarwin mentioned, the definitions for tables containing primary keys referenced by the `trans` table should appear *before* the definition for the `trans` table.  So you should move the definition for the `trans` table to last.

*However*, even doing this *still* results in an error in SQLFiddle:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/175aca) (uncomment the foreign key reference in `trans`)

SQLFiddle seems to have some sort of problem with accepting this table schema.  This is not surprising, as the site seems to have such problems frequently.

Answer (score 1):

What is order you create tables. You need first to create product and user1 and at the end - trans.